# Efficient Context-Free Grammar parser, preferably Python-friendly

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, grammar, nltk

I am in need of parsing a small subset of English for one of my project, described as a context-free grammar with (1-level) feature structures ([example](http://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk/examples/grammars/book_grammars/feat0.fcfg?r=8260)) and I need to do it efficiently .

Right now I'm using [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)'s parser which produces the right output but is very slow. For my grammar of ~450 fairly ambiguous non-lexicon rules and half a million lexical entries, parsing simple sentences can take anywhere from 2 to 30 seconds, depending it seems on the number of resulting trees. Lexical entries have little to no effect on performance.

Another problem is that loading the (25MB) grammar+lexicon at the beginning can take up to a minute.

From what I can find in literature, the running time of the algorithm used to parse such a grammar (Earley or CKY) should be linear to the size of the grammar and cubic to the size of the input token list. My experience with NLTK indicates that ambiguity is what hurts the performance most, not the absolute size of the grammar.

So now I'm looking for a CFG parser to replace NLTK. I've been considering [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) but I can't tell whether it supports feature structures in CFGs, which are required in my case, and the examples I've seen seem to be doing a lot of procedural parsing rather than just specifying a grammar. Can anybody show me an example of PLY both supporting feature structs and using a declarative grammar?

I'm also fine with any other parser that can do what I need efficiently. A Python interface is preferable but not absolutely necessary.

Comment: I'm just looking for the same thing but only for Java. Here is my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584684/java-cfg-parser-that-supports-ambiguities . So which method did you decide? Apalala says that we can fix ANTLR to handle ambiguities. However I didn't understand the method he suggests.

Comment: So far I'm still using NLTK as none of the libraries or techniques in the answers worked for me. However, that is in part because I require a unification grammar (CFG + feature structs) and according to the NLTK developer in charge of the parser, my efficiency problems stem from that.

Comment: Here is a list of Python parsers: https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing

Answer (score 18):

By all means take a look at [Pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing). It's the most pythonic implementations of parsing I've come across, and it's a great design from a purely academic standpoint.

I used both [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) and [JavaCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaCC) to teach translator and compiler theory at a local university. They're both good and mature, but I wouldn't use them in a Python project.

That said, unlike programming languages, natural languages are much more about the semantics than about the syntax, so you could be much better off skipping the learning curves of existing parsing tools, going with a home-brewed (top-down, backtracking, unlimited lookahead) lexical analyzer and parser, and spending the bulk of your time writing the code that figures out what a parsed, but ambiguous, natural-language sentence means.

Comment: IMX pyparsing adds quite a bit of unnecessary overhead. It's also not really built with the idea of separate lexing and parsing steps in mind.

Comment: The separation of tokenizer and parser is an arbitrary legacy from tools like LEX/YACC, and from times in which computing power was such that even thinking about a single-pass compiler was crazy. If the grammar language is powerful enough to define the target language at all levels, then the separation is not needed. Designers have long used EBNF to define all parts of a programming language, and though ANTLR provides for separation, it uses context free grammars (nor regular expressions) for lexical analysis. So does Pyparsing.

Comment: Just like ANTLR, Pyparsing does not seem to (1) handle CFGs and (2) properly generate all trees for an ambiguous parse. Both of these are required in my case. Regarding your note on natural languages, you're correct. The bulk of the project is semantic analysis, and I'm already doing it with my own code. However, I need to get the parse trees before I can disambiguate them. Writing my own is an option but on the whole I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Max Shawabkeh Pyparsing or not, there's an old trick from my Prolog days you can use to get all of the parse trees with any top-down parsing tool. If your grammar is G-> <alpha>, change it to:

G' -> G {semantic-clone-parse-tree} <TOKEN-NOT-IN-LANGUAGE>

That is, clone the complete parse tree right before forcing the parser to fail the parse. Cloning instead of saving is necessary because the parser will modify the tree while it seeks a different parse.

Answer (score 3):

I've used pyparsing for limited vocabulary command parsing, but here is a little framework on top of pyparsing that addresses your posted example:

```
from pyparsing import *

transVerb, transVerbPlural, transVerbPast, transVerbProg = (Forward() for i in range(4))
intransVerb, intransVerbPlural, intransVerbPast, intransVerbProg = (Forward() for i in range(4))
singNoun,pluralNoun,properNoun = (Forward() for i in range(3))
singArticle,pluralArticle = (Forward() for i in range(2))
verbProg = transVerbProg | intransVerbProg
verbPlural = transVerbPlural | intransVerbPlural

for expr in (transVerb, transVerbPlural, transVerbPast, transVerbProg,
            intransVerb, intransVerbPlural, intransVerbPast, intransVerbProg,
            singNoun, pluralNoun, properNoun, singArticle, pluralArticle):
    expr << MatchFirst([])

def appendExpr(e1, s):
    c1 = s[0]
    e2 = Regex(r"[%s%s]%s\b" % (c1.upper(), c1.lower(), s[1:]))
    e1.expr.exprs.append(e2)

def makeVerb(s, transitive):
    v_pl, v_sg, v_past, v_prog = s.split()
    if transitive:
        appendExpr(transVerb, v_sg)
        appendExpr(transVerbPlural, v_pl)
        appendExpr(transVerbPast, v_past)
        appendExpr(transVerbProg, v_prog)
    else:
        appendExpr(intransVerb, v_sg)
        appendExpr(intransVerbPlural, v_pl)
        appendExpr(intransVerbPast, v_past)
        appendExpr(intransVerbProg, v_prog)

def makeNoun(s, proper=False):
    if proper:
        appendExpr(properNoun, s)
    else:
        n_sg,n_pl = (s.split() + [s+"s"])[:2]
        appendExpr(singNoun, n_sg)
        appendExpr(pluralNoun, n_pl)

def makeArticle(s, plural=False):
    for ss in s.split():
        if not plural:
            appendExpr(singArticle, ss)
        else:
            appendExpr(pluralArticle, ss)

makeVerb("disappear disappears disappeared disappearing", transitive=False)
makeVerb("walk walks walked walking", transitive=False)
makeVerb("see sees saw seeing", transitive=True)
makeVerb("like likes liked liking", transitive=True)

makeNoun("dog")
makeNoun("girl")
makeNoun("car")
makeNoun("child children")
makeNoun("Kim", proper=True)
makeNoun("Jody", proper=True)

makeArticle("a the")
makeArticle("this every")
makeArticle("the these all some several", plural=True)

transObject = (singArticle + singNoun | properNoun | Optional(pluralArticle) + pluralNoun | verbProg | "to" + verbPlural)
sgSentence = (singArticle + singNoun | properNoun) + (intransVerb | intransVerbPast | (transVerb | transVerbPast) + transObject)
plSentence = (Optional(pluralArticle) + pluralNoun) + (intransVerbPlural | intransVerbPast | (transVerbPlural |transVerbPast) + transObject)

sentence = sgSentence | plSentence


def test(s):
    print s
    try:
        print sentence.parseString(s).asList()
    except ParseException, pe:
        print pe

test("Kim likes cars")
test("The girl saw the dog")
test("The dog saw Jody")
test("Kim likes walking")
test("Every girl likes dogs")
test("All dogs like children")
test("Jody likes to walk")
test("Dogs like walking")
test("All dogs like walking")
test("Every child likes Jody")
```

Prints:

```
Kim likes cars
['Kim', 'likes', 'cars']
The girl saw the dog
['The', 'girl', 'saw', 'the', 'dog']
The dog saw Jody
['The', 'dog', 'saw', 'Jody']
Kim likes walking
['Kim', 'likes', 'walking']
Every girl likes dogs
['Every', 'girl', 'likes', 'dogs']
All dogs like children
['All', 'dogs', 'like', 'children']
Jody likes to walk
['Jody', 'likes', 'to', 'walk']
Dogs like walking
['Dogs', 'like', 'walking']
All dogs like walking
['All', 'dogs', 'like', 'walking']
Every child likes Jody
['Every', 'child', 'likes', 'Jody']
```

This is likely to get slow as you expand the vocabulary. Half a million entries?  I thought that a reasonable functional vocabulary was on the order of 5-6 thousand words. And you will be pretty limited in the sentence structures that you can handle - natural language is what NLTK is for.

Comment: Thanks for such a large example but this uses a procedural approach that is quite bulky when you have such a large number of rules. I would very much prefer to use a parser that understands EBNF. As for the lexicon, you are correct, 50K words should be enough. However, adding lexicon entries doesn't really affect performance - using a bottom up parser terminals require a single dictionary lookup, and even if we say it's O(log n), which it's not, an order of magnitude increase in the vocabulary is insignificant. It's the ambiguous non-terminal rules that are the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Tooling aside...

You may remember from theory that there are infinite grammars that define the same language. There are criteria for categorizing grammars and determining which is the "canonical" or "minimal" one for a given language, but in the end, the "best" grammar is the one that's more convenient for the task and tools at hand (remember the transformations of CFGs into LL and LR grammars?).

Then, you probably don't need a huge lexicon to parse an sentence in English. There's a lot to be known about a word in languages like German or Latin (or even Spanish), but not in the many times arbitrary and ambiguos English. You should be able to get away with a small lexicon that contains only the key words necessary to arrive to the structure of a sentence. At any rate, the grammar you choose, no matter its size, can be cached in a way that thee tooling can directly use it (i.e., you can skip parsing the grammar).

Given that, it could be a good idea to take a look at a simpler parser already worked on by someone else. There must be thousands of those in the literature. Studying different approaches will let you evaluate your own, and may lead you to adopt someone else's.

Finally, as I already mentioned, interpreting natural languages is much more about artificial intelligence than about parsing. Because structure determines meaning and meaning determines structure you have to play with both at the same time. An approach I've seen in the literature since the '80s is to let different specialized agents take shots at solving the problem against a "[blackboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_system)". With that approach syntatic and semantic analysis happen concurrently.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment to Paul's post, the lexicon is not an issue in regards to performance. Caching the grammar is obvious and I'm doing it already, so the loading time is a secondary concern. However, it should be mentioned that an NLTK parser pickled to disk and reloaded loads slower than creating a new one from the grammar.

Regarding using an existing parser, the problem with the semantic analysis approach I'm using (a variation of Montague grammar / DRT) is that it requires me to write a semantic processing step for each syntactic rule...

Comment: ...and the rules have to be crafted in a certain way. Most wide-coverage grammars I've seen approach the issue by collecting a huge number of long rules empirically extracted from treebanks and assigning probabilities to them. This approach is valid for some uses, but not in my case.

Comment: I guess my point is that, for natural languages, there isn't enough information to do semantic analysis during the syntactic analysis, and there's not enough semantic information to accurately grasp the syntactic structure with a typical parser. "Mary read that Jane read well. What Jane read, Mary read as well."

Comment: That's where ambiguity comes in. I can parse a sentence syntactically with almost no semantic knowledge (except for the bits encoded in the lexicon) and once I have all possible parse trees, I do a semantic analysis step, and find which trees are acceptable.

Comment: @Max Shawabkeh. Your approach is valid, but it's brute force, so the problems with resources (memory/time) should be expected (I'm reminded of the animations of sorteing algorithms). To deal with the resource issues, you could at least start discarding trees as soon as you find them with a concurrent semantic analyzer. Theoretical time would be the same, but computer time could drop drastically just because you would be using less memory. If the parser builds intermediate trees, then it would do well to incorporate game theory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star).

Comment: My disambiguation approach does not really work without a complete tree to analyze. In fact, any disambiguator that analyzes incomplete tree risks discarding valid ones simply because any subtree that might be semantically incoherent can give rise to a perfectly valid tree when e.g. put inside a conditional or negation. In any case, (1) the speed issues arise even when I get <10 trees so discarding any wouldn't help and (2) the CKY/Earley parsing algorithms used are NOT brute force searches and do not grow exponentially. CKY's runtime is O(g*n^3), where g is grammar size and n is input size.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using bitpar, a very efficient PCFG parser written in C++. I've written a shell-based Python wrapper for it, see https://github.com/andreasvc/eodop/blob/master/bitpar.py

Answer (score 1):

I think ANTLR is the best parser-generator that I know of for Java.  I don't know if Jython would provide you a good way for Python and Java to interact.

Comment: ANTLR actually supports Python, among a few other languages: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets

Comment: Didn't know that; I've only used it for Java.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. However, from what I can see ANTLR (and all its relatives, Lex/Yacc, Bison, etc.) are mainly written for parsing deterministic programming languages rather than ambiguous natural languages. In my case a medium-length sentence might result in 20 parse trees and I need to generate them all. Note: The downvote is not mine.

Comment: Natural language parsing is a difficult problem.  I'm not aware that it's solved.  You said "context-free" - I don't think that's true for natural languages like English.  Context matters.  If I understand the terms correctly, "natural language" and "context free" are contradictory.  I'll admit that I'm not an expert.

Comment: Yes, most natural langues (including English) are not context free, however, a large and very useful subset of it can be expressed in a sufficiently complex ambiguous CFG, which can then be disambiguated semantically.

Comment: Exactly. Natural languages are not context-free.

Comment: @Max - "can be disambiguated semantically" might not be so easy.  The one effort that I know of to do such a thing (Doug Lenat's Cyc http://www.cyc.com/cyc/opencyc) is a huge undertaking that's more than a decade old.

Comment: Cyc is the largest such project, but WordNet is also a fairly mature attempt at creating a semantic hierarchy. In any case, the disambiguation and symantic analysis part is the meat of my project so that is not the issue I'm trying to solve with this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat late on this, but here are two more options for you:

[Spark](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~aycock/spark/) is a Earley parser written in Python.

[Elkhound](http://scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/) is a GLR parser written in C++  Elkhound uses a Bison like syntax

Answer (score 0):

If it can be expressed as a [PEG](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/parsing%3apopl04.pdf) language (I don't think all CFGs can, but supposedly many can), then you might use [pyPEG](http://fdik.org/pyPEG/), which is supposed to be linear-time when using a packrat parsing implementation (although potentially prohibitive on memory usage).

I don't have any experience with it as I am just starting to research parsing and compilation again after a long time away from it, but I am reading some good buzz about this relatively up-to-date technique.  YMMV.

Comment: From what I can tell that approach is a way to resolve ambiguities inside an EBNFish grammar through prioritization and such, which is certainly useful but counter-productive in my case since I actually want the ambiguity to remain.

Comment: Yes, it does say it is not usable for languages which depend on ambiguities.