# Java CFG parser that supports ambiguities

Tags: java, nlp, context-free-grammar

I'm looking for a CFG parser implemented with Java. The thing is I'm trying to parse a natural language. And I need all possible parse trees (ambiguity) not only one of them. I already researched many NLP parsers such as Stanford parser. But they mostly require statistical data (a treebank which I don't have) and it is rather difficult and poorly documented to adapt them in to a new language.
I found some parser generators such as ANTRL or JFlex but I'm not sure that they can handle ambiguities.  So which parser generator or java library is best for me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a parser that uses the Earley algorithm. I haven't used either of these two libraries, but [PEN](http://code.google.com/p/pen/) and [PEP](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~scott/#projects-pep) appear implement this algorithm in Java.

Comment: Thanks for answer, after taking a look at PEP, I think this is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), which implements [GLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser).  GLR is an LR type parsing algorithm that supports ambiguous grammars.  Bison also generates Java code, in addition to C++.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543008/efficient-context-free-grammar-parser-preferably-python-friendly/4546821). In my last comment in that discussion I explain that you can make any parser generator produce all of the parse trees by cloning the parse tree derived so far before making the derivation fail.

If your grammar is:

```
G -> ...
```

You would augment is as this:

```
G' -> G {semantic:deal-with-complete-parse-tree} <NOT-VALID-TOKEN>.
```

The parsing engine will ultimately fail on all derivations, but your program will either have:

- Saved clones of all the trees.
- Dealt with the semantics of each of the trees as they were found.

Both ANTLR and JavaCC did well when I was teaching. My preference was for ANTLR because of its BNF lexical analysis, and its much less convoluted history, vision, y and licensing.

Comment: Apalala thanks for the answer. Actually I haven't worked with parser generators yet. Do you think it is the best solution in my case. Because once I start to learn ANTLR it going to take time and I have already wasted some to finish my thesis.

Comment: @hrzafer There are plenty of grammars available for mainstream parser generators. You'll likely find one you can adapt to your needs. As to time, only you can estimate that. It might be useful to know that when I taught, the first assignment with ANTLR/JavaCC was due the third week, and it was a 6-hours/week subject (a thesis should be 20-40 hours/week endeavour).