# Implementation of functions with very basic scripting

Tags: python, programming-languages

I've been playing around with python for some time and decided to better my generalized understanding of programming languages by writing a custom script handler in python. I have so far successfully implemented a basic memory handler and hooked a memory address ordinate to printing to the screen. My question can be posed as:

How can functions be implemented here? A goto statement is too easy, I would like to try something more difficult. (edit) Eventually i want to be able to do:

```
f0(x, y, z):=ax^by^cz
```

...in a shell that runs a script that runs this module (silly, eh?)

```
# notes: separate addresses from data lest the loop of doom cometh

class Interpreter:

  def __init__(self):
    self.memory = { }
    self.dictionary = {"mov" : self.mov,
                       "put" : self.put,
                       "add" : self.add,
                       "sub" : self.sub,
                       "clr" : self.clr,
                       "cpy" : self.cpy,
                       "ref" : self.ref }
    self.hooks = {self.val("0") : self.out }

  def interpret(self, line):
    x = line.split(" ")
    vals = tuple(self.val(y) for y in x[1:])
    dereferenced = []
    keys_only = tuple(key for key in self.memory)
    for val in vals:
      while val in self.memory: val = self.memory[val]
      dereferenced.append(val)
    vals = tuple(y for y in dereferenced)
    self.dictionary[x[0]](vals)

  def val(self, x):
    return tuple(int(y) for y in str(x).split("."))

  def mov(self, value):
    self.ptr = value[0]

  def put(self, value):
    self.memory[self.ptr] = value[0]

  def clr(self, value):
    if self.ptr in self.hooks and self.ptr in self.memory:
      x = self.hooks[self.ptr]
      y = self.memory[self.ptr]
      for z in y: x(z)
    del self.memory[self.ptr]

  def add(self, values):
    self.put(self.mat(values, lambda x, y: x + y))

  def sub(self, values):
    self.put(self.mat(values, lambda x, y: x - y))

  def mat(self, values, op):
    a, b = self.memory[values[0]], self.memory[values[1]]
    if len(a) > len(b): a, b = b, a
    c = [op(a[x], b[x]) for x in xrange(len(b))] + [x for x in a[len(a):]]
    return [tuple(x for x in c)]

  def cpy(self, value):
    self.put(value)

  def out(self, x):
    print chr(x),

  def ref(self, x):
    self.put(x)

interp = Interpreter()
for x in file(__file__.split('/')[-1].split(".")[-2] + ".why"):
  interp.interpret(x.strip())
```

a sample script:

```
mov 1
put 104.101.108.108.111.10
mov 0
ref 1
clr 0
```

(EDIT) I've made the decision to use this attempt as inspiration and start from scratch on this project. (Hopefully I'll find some real time to sit down and code before classes start up again.) <strike>I intend to award the best answer in a few days</strike>. I hope that that information fails to dissuade potential contributors from submitting anything they feel to be helpful for this sort of coding problem.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific that just "basic input/output functions", but basically it looks like you could do whatever it is the same way you've done everything else...i.e. add one or more commands to your interpreter.

Comment: I replaced that question with a better (more specific) one.

Comment: @Sean Pedersen It will be easier to answer if you show how it should behave (some real-action tests, passed or failed).

Comment: As a sidenote, instead of that dictionary you could call each method by doing getattr(self, x[0])(vals)

Comment: @Bemmu, I chose to use dictionaries because I think they are easier on the eyes.

Comment: @DrTyrsa, see edit at second paragraph.

Comment: @Sean: Why not simply do `self.dict = self.__dict__`? Or just utilize `self.__dict__` itself. There's no need for you to create a new dictionary when one already exists.

Comment: @JAB, separate namespaces is probably a good idea. Perhaps you don't want to expose `interpret()`, or later want to add keys that conflict with Python keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am struggling a bit to understand what you are asking. Where is your function definition to be given? In the script handler or in the script?

If it is in the script handler, the obvious solution would be to use the [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda) expression. Using the example you used in the question `f0(x, y, z):=x^2` would translate in:

```
>>> f0 = lambda x, y, z : x**2
>>> f0(2,3,4)
4
```

If the function definitions are to be placed in the script itself, you could get away with a combination of `lambda` and [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) expressions. Here's a quick example that I just hammered together to illustrate the idea.

```
class ScriptParser(object):

    # See 'to_python' to check out what this does
    mapping = {'^':'**', '!':' not ', '&':' and '}

    def to_python(self, calc):
        '''
        Parse the calculation syntax from the script grammar to the python one.
        This could be grown to a more complex parser, if needed. For now it will
        simply assume any operator as defined in the grammar used for the script
        has an equivalent in python.
        '''
        for k, v in self.mapping.items():
            calc = calc.replace(k, v)
        return calc

    def feed(self, lfs):
        '''
        Parse a line of the script containing a function defintion
        '''
        signature, calc = lfs.split(':=')
        funcname, variables = [s.strip() for s in signature.split('(')]
        # as we stripped the strings, it's now safe to do...'
        variables = variables[:-1]
        setattr(self, funcname,
                eval('lambda ' + variables + ' : ' + self.to_python(calc)))

def main():
    lines = ['f0(x, y, z) := x^2',
             'f1(x) := x**2 + x**3 + x*1000']
    sp = ScriptParser()
    for line in lines:
        sp.feed(line)
        print('Script definition  : %s' % line)
    for i in range(5):
        res0 = sp.f0(i, None, None)
        res1 = sp.f1(i)
        print('f0(%d) = %d' % (i, res0))
        print('f1(%d) = %d' % (i, res1))
        print('--------')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running this program outputs:

```
Script definition  : f0(x, y, z) := x^2
Script definition  : f1(x) := x**2 + x**3 + x*1000
f0(0) = 0
f1(0) = 0
--------
f0(1) = 1
f1(1) = 1002
--------
f0(2) = 4
f1(2) = 2012
--------
f0(3) = 9
f1(3) = 3036
--------
f0(4) = 16
f1(4) = 4080
--------
```

Keep in mind though that:

1. Using `eval` has security implications that you should be aware of.
2. Writing your own grammar parser is a truly cool learning experience!! :)

HTH,
Mac.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to a compiler manual, it will advise to use stacks when calling methods. That will allow you to create recursive functions, a function that calls other functions, and also keep you variables in proper scope.

So you use a stack to stack up your variables for each function call, and yes, use `goto` to go to the address of the function. Then use your stack to get the return address of the function, and the state of the variables when the function was called. That's it.

Good luck!

Comment: In addition to one or more stacks, some general and/or special-purpose registers could also prove to be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I'm understanding you right, but if your goal is to be able to define a function by doing `f0(x):=mov x` and other complex syntaxes, then it sounds to me like the big components you're missing are some sort of lexical analysis and a grammar parser.  Once you get away from the concept of "first symbol on the line defines what the line does", then your method of `line.split(" ")` is no longer sufficient. These are pretty complex tools, and every language more complex than assembly requires these tools (though they may be built by hand, depending on the language and compiler/interpreter).

Most parse their inputs in two primary steps:

1) Lexical Analysis -- This step takes "x+1/5" and translates it into meaningful symbols like "VARIABLE OPERATOR NUMBER OPERATOR NUMBER".  The output from this step is used as the input to the grammar parser

2) Grammar parsing -- This is more complex, and there's a large amount of theory on the best ways to do grammar parsing.  This will take the above input and parse it into a tree that can be evaluated.  Like:

```
Operator+ 
|     |
|     ----Variable x 
Operator/
|    |
1    5
```

I don't have any experience with either of these types of tools in Python. In C++, the only tools I've used are called flex, and bison.  I'm sure someone else here has used tools like these before in python, and could point you to some links.  Looks like this question has some: [Efficient Context-Free Grammar parser, preferably Python-friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543008/efficient-context-free-grammar-parser-preferably-python-friendly)

I tried searching for some tutorials for ya on the concepts, but came up blank.  My googling skills are not turned on tonight, for some reason.

Comment: I feel terrible now for not being specific enough. :/ The intended function definition is to be something more like `f1(x):=x^2`. I've been receiving numerous helpful and insightful answers here and on Code Review. Top-notch answer, Xepo.

Comment: Ah, if you want to do full expression parsing, you'll almost definitely need a grammar parser.  Do a search for how to implement a calculator using a grammar parser in python, and you should come up with some good examples.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) to define your grammar.  There are lots of [examples](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples) on its wiki, such as an [interactive calculator](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/SimpleCalc.py).