# How to use generators or yield to recursively find the model hierarchy?

Tags: python, recursive-query

For simplicity, we have a geometry model which contains the chained/linked objects in a file `"mymodel.txt"`. The objective is to find all the dependent children objects belonging to a parent object, say `"surfname1"` by the linked names in the hierarchy or similarly from inherited classes. Note all objects have end marker `";"`

```
[mymodel.txt]...
 FramePoint pointname0 * / 0.0 0.000 0.000 ;
 FramePoint pointname1 * / 1.0 0.000 0.000 ;
 FramePoint pointname2 * / 10.0 0.000 10.000 ;
 FramePoint pointname3 * / 10.0 10.000 10.000 ;
 FramePoint pointname4 * / 10.0 10.000 10.000 ;
#  ... 
 FramePoint pointnameX * / 0.0 0.000 0.000 ;
# ...
 CCurve curvename1 / pointname1 pointname2 pointname3
                     pointname4 ;  
 IntBead bead1 / curvename1 *Z=0 pointname0 ;
 BSubCurve curvename2 / pointname0 ;
# BSubCurve ...
 CLoftSurf surfname1 / curvename1 curvename2 ;
# ...

import os
import logging
import pathlib
import re
def findstr_in_file(str2find:str, inpfile, pattern:str='', G_line=None):

    G_line += G_line if G_line else ''

    file_path = pathlib.Path(inpfile)
    try:
        with file_path.open(mode="r") as file:
            for l_no, line in enumerate(file):
                for match in re.finditer(pattern + str2find, line):
                    # not found 3 numerics like 1.0002 2.0005 4.0009
                    if not re.findall('[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ +[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ +[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ +', line[line.rfind('/') + 1:]):
                        print(f'Line Number:{l_no}; Line:{line}')
                        # append the following lines until end marker   
                        while not ';' in line:
                            line += next(file)
                        yield line
                        str = re.findall(r'\b[^\*|=]\w+\b', line[line.rfind('/') + 1:])
                        for objname in str:
                            if len(objname):
                                findstr_in_file(objname, inpfile, pattern, G_line)
                        break
                    else:
                        yield line
                        break
    except OSError as error:
        logging.error(f'Reading file {file_path} failed due to: {error}')

# ******** The definition: ObjectType ObjectName + specification ********
# so the search pattern is \w+ and space and \w+ 
G_line = ''
findstr_in_file('surfname1', 'mymodel.txt', '(\w+ +)', G_line)
```

Comment: do you have a specification for the file you are trying to parse? It seems rather confuse - and the hardcoded regexps won't help here - one will need to tokenize and parse this properly.

Comment: That really should to be done with a context free grammar such as PyParsing (https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html) or one of several alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543008/efficient-context-free-grammar-parser-preferably-python-friendly

Comment: The original model file is from worked example in Multisurf and I have simplified for parsing purpose. It seems that the detailed entity/object specifications are not easy to access from the official website http://www.multisurf.com, but this might be helpful http://www.multisurf.com/test/MarineTutorials.pdf.